# Why does MPlayer OSX Extended generate fontconfig on my desktop?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, mplayer, fontconfig

I use MPlayer OSX Extended as my primary video player.  However, every time I play a video, a fontconfig folder appears on my desktop containing a few random .cache-3 files.  Deleting this folder will cause it to be regenerated and disabling fontconfig entirely prevents text in videos from being displayed.

I somehow managed to fix this on my old computer several years ago, but I can't remember what I did.

How can I get MPlayer to stop dumping it's fontconfig cache on my desktop?

Comment: Don't have this, so can't test for sure, but lots of programs use the $HOME environment value.  This is usually set to your homedir, though, not your Desktop.  But, try setting this env var to a different dir, log out, relaunch.  Does the fontconfig dir follow $HOME?

Comment: @jimtut Changing the $HOME var had no effect.  It still dumps to the Desktop, even when $HOME is not set to my Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On version 15, the fonts.conf file (`MPlayer OS Extended.app/Contents/Resources/fonts`) shows the font cache directory list as the following:

```
<cachedir>/opt/local/var/cache/fontconfig</cachedir>
<cachedir>/usr/X11/var/cache/fontconfig</cachedir>
<cachedir prefix="xdg">fontconfig</cachedir>
<!-- the following element will be removed in the future -->
<cachedir>~/.fontconfig</cachedir>
```

For some reason, the `~/.fontconfig` location is no longer used.  Instead, the first two locations are checked, and if both fail, the user's Desktop is used as a fallback location.

In my case, I had no `/usr/X11/var/` folder and the permissions were such that no ordinary user could create one.  Manually creating `/usr/X11/var/cache/` and allowing all users to write to the cache folder let MPlayer generate the fontconfig folder inside cache and kept it off my desktop.